# Selection from a drop down menu isn't being inserted to assigned variable

Tags: php

I have used nearly this exact code on another page and it worked great, but here... not so much.

I have a drop down menu populated with elements from database columns. Whichever element is selected should be stored in the variable `$Product`, but for some reason I cannot figure out, it is simply not making it there and the rest of my script (parts I didn't post) doesn't work. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $Product = $_POST['Product_List'];
    } else {
        $Product = "";
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Add Chemical Inventory</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="form_div">
            <div id="form_label">
                <h2>Add Chemical Inventory</h2>
                <form action="Add_Chemical_Inventory.php">
                    <?php
                    $List = "SELECT Product_ID, Product_Name FROM `products`";
                    $list_result = mysqli_query($connection,$List); 
                    echo "Product: <select name='Product_List'>";
                    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($list_result)){
                        echo "<option value='".$row['Product_ID'] ."'>".$row['Product_Name']."</option>";
                    }
                    echo "</select>";
                    echo "<br />";
                    ?>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"it is simply not making it there and the rest of my script (parts I didn't post) doesn't work"_ This does not meet the criteria for a clear problem description.

Comment: I can't help but notice you never actually connected to a database???

Comment: Sorry...it's in an include file that I didn't add to my question. Everything else works in this, but for some reason the Product_ID that should make it to $Product never does. Variable stays empty.

Comment: I can post the entire page if that would be helpful. I was trying to be concise.

Comment: Post the [MCVE] you've been debugging with for the past few days, as instructed by the Tour you took two days ago!

Comment: Hmmm...didn't take the tour. Might be part of my problem.

Comment: I don't really know if this is the issue, but I think you missed the `method` attribute on your `<form>` tag. Thing is, by default, the method is set to `get`, and since your code expects `post` data, it just doesn't save it to the variable. Hope this was it, try it out!

Comment: Zeke, I can't believe I omitted that, but it absolutely worked. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: I am glad it worked. In such case, I'll add the answer so you can mark it as the solution and then everyone can make use of it in the future :) Happy coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the `method` attribute on your `<form>` tag.

Thing is, by default, the method is set to `get`, and since your code expects `post` data, it just doesn't save it to the variable.

```
<form action="Add_Chemical_Inventory.php" method="post"></form>
```